# Redirecting To a New Angular Application After Login and Subscription Success

Tags: html, django, angular

Good Day Everyone, Please I am working on a personal project on Angular, I have two angular applications, the main angular application and the second angular application to redirect to after login and subscription has been validated.

The Only issue now is how to make use of the home.component.html of the second application which contains different menu or navbar items  but each time i redirect to the second application, the items or menu showing on the navbar are the main or default application component.html but with the second angular application contents. I also discovered that second application was not generated with any index.html file.

Please I need help on how to go about this. In summary two angular applications one acting as default (thriller page), the second to display the real contents for movies. How can i implement the default application having its own menu and the second application having its own menu as well. Thanks

Comment: did you try using an anchor tag pointing to the second app?

Comment: I only used link like /home/ and /dashmovies/ going by what you said for home i will have something like localhost:/streamclient/app/app.component.html for home. I will have to implement this to see if it will work. Thanks

Comment: I implemented it and it did not work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href = 'SecondAppUrl';` to navigate to the second app.

Comment: I tried it but not working. These are some of the paths set for the second angular application.{path: 'home', component: StreamHomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  //{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {path: 'dashmovies', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'dashmovies/:slug', component: DashboardDetailComponent},
  {path: 'streamactionmovies', component: StreamactionListComponent},
  {path: 'streamactionmovies/:slug', component: StreamactionDetailComponent},

Comment: the two angular application are in the same folder having different app.component.html with name AppComponent and StreamAppComponent   respectively. So the contents in the first app.component.html is different from the second one. The first angular app has Movies as one of the Navbar menu while the second angular has another name for the same menu after login in.

Comment: can you please show the URL you used in the code ?/